# Cannot install Wine in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wine

I installed Linux Mint Maya Xfce. When I tried to install Wine, it gets stuck and no progress is made beyond 83% installed.

I used the Software Manager. I have tried using the command line as advised here above, but it still no joy.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Are there any errors? What is the output when you install via the command line when you do `sudo apt-get install wine`?

Comment: good idea to `apt-get purge wine` and maybe clear your tmp folder and have you changed your repos?

Comment: Can you post the output of "sudo apt-get install wine" and the content of the file "/etc/apt/sources.list"?

Answer (score 0):

There has been a "mystery problem" installing WINE v1.4 and v1.5 in both Mint and Ubuntu.  It is supposed to be fixed in v1.6, but has not been released, yet.  Since there are several other problems with WINE v1.5, the interim fix is to install wine-gecko1.4 from the command line.  Apt-get will install WINE v1.4 as a dependency and the installation will go fine.

```
sudo apt-get wine-gecko1.4:amd64
```

or

```
sudo apt-get wine-gecko1.4:i386
```